# How to get values in window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, location-href

Code:

```
window.location.href = "Posts?Category=" + sel;
```

How to get the value in Category page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function getURLParameter(name, urlsearch) {

        return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(urlsearch || location.search) || [ , "" ])[1].replace(
                /\+/g, '%20'))
                || null;
    }

    var url = "Posts?Category=1134324";

    alert(getURLParameter('Category', url));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kL9DJ/