# Pass the Data of FORM_1 (page1.html ) to FORM_2 (page.html) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a code that will show the value of `form1` to another page.
Now, This +(plus sign) keeps on showing and substituting the spaces.
Is there anyone can help me here?

Thank you so much.

Below are my codes:

**Page1.html**

```
<form type=get action="page2.html">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name:</td>
      <td><input type=text name=firstname size=10></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last
        Name:
      </td>
      <td><input type=text name=lastname size=10></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Age:</td>
      <td><input type=text name=age size=10
        id="age"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2><input type=submit
        value="Submit"> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

**Page2.html**

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
  function getParams() {
    var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
    var params = new Array();
    if (idx != -1) {
      var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx + 1,
        document.URL.length).split('&');
      for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
        params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
      }
    }
    return params;
  }
  params = getParams();
  firstname =
     unescape(params["firstname"]);
  lastname =
     unescape(params["lastname"]);
  age = unescape(params["age"]);

  ages = age;
  document.write("firstname = " + firstname + "<br>");
  document.write("lastname = " + lastname + "<br>");
  document.write("<input type=text name=age size=10 value=" + ages +
    ">");
</script>
```

Comment: kindly fromat your code properly.its really hard to read

Comment: I don't see where you get the lastname? but try decodeURIComponent(lastname). Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116962/how-to-get-values-in-window-location-href/20117046#20117046

Comment: Thanks for the comment guys. @Andrew: It's in the page1.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [decodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp) to decode the plus signs back into spaces, and [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) to encode it on the first page.

You also don't need to be using substring so much to try and manually parse the URL:

```
var url = location.href.split("?");
var params = url[1].split("&");
var data = {};

for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++)
{
    var param = params[i].split("=");
    data[param[0]] = param[1];
}
```

At the end of that code, you'll have an object `data` that contains keys of the parameter names you pass in :)

Comment: Thanks Collin for the answer. When I tried your code it's not functioning. May you please elaborate it more? Thank you once again. :)

Comment: What do you mean by not functioning? Are you doing anything with the `data` object that is created?

Comment: I actually copy pasted your code to my code in the page2.html and there are no content showed.

Comment: My code does not print anything; you need to `document.write` it still if you want that, but use `data.firstname` and `data.lastname` instead of your `firstname` and `lastname` variables.

Comment: Sorry Collin. But I think I don't understand it anymore. i'm not that good in javascript but can you please write it here on how you'll implement it, I mean the codes? Because when I tried it there's no content showing. I hope you understand. Thanks.

Comment: You already have the code for writing it... `document.write("firstname = " + firstname + "<br>");` - just change it to this: `document.write("firstname = " + data.firstname + "<br>");`

Comment: Okay I made it into this: http://pastebin.com/jwr76VuE Please look if I'm doing fine. Because i tried loading it, it shows still nothing in my content area.. Thanks.